# Show only the number of sha digits that are required to make it unique it git log?

Tags: git

`git log` provides a unique sha to represent any given commit that it is giving information about.

```
commit 6793960b9e333d77b99405f84c78888e41d6c712  <--- THIS
Author: Cory Klein <cory.klein@------.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 18 11:45:51 2013 -0600

    Delete local files after transfer
```

We occasionally pass these shas around to refer to commits on the team. It would be neat if `git log` only showed the number of digits that were necessary to refer to that specific commit at the time the `git log` command was run:

```
commit 67939  <--- Only 5 digits are needed to make this sha unique
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man git-log`:

```
--abbrev-commit
   Instead of showing the full 40-byte hexadecimal commit object name, show
   only a partial prefix. Non default number of digits can be specified with
   "--abbrev=<n>" (which also modifies diff output, if it is displayed).

   This should make "--pretty=oneline" a whole lot more readable for people
   using 80-column terminals.
```

So:

```
git log --abbrev-commit
```

Comment: That doesn't completely answer the question. It lets you specify a fixed number of digits, but it doesn't calculate how many digits are actually needed for uniqueness.

Comment: One data point: The Linux kernel repository at git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git currently has 387742 commits; 9 hex digits are enough to uniquely identify all of them. But you *could* get unlucky and have two commits whose ids are identical in the first N digits for any value of N up to 40, (though a 40-digit collision is [fantastically unlikely](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) (search for "wolves").

Comment: The phrase "40-byte hexadecimal commit object name" is a little misleading. It's a 40-digit string representing a 20-byte object.

Answer (score 0):

```
commit 67939  <--- Only 5 digits are needed to make this sha unique
```

that is true for right now, Your next commit could very well be 67939111111111111111 which would clash with that.

That being said there is a reduced version which can be accessed with git log --abbrev-commit

Comment: I am aware of this, and it is why I specifically mentioned "at the time the `git log` command was run"

Comment: "We occasionally pass these shas around to refer to commits on the team." it may not mean a huge amount looking back though Great at the time

Comment: Understandable. Usually the sha's are "passed around" with a specific context though, so if down the road the sha becomes ambiguous, it is pretty easy to figure out specifically which actual commit the truncated version is referring to. For me, the reduced cost up front is worth the very occasional increased cost down the road.

Answer (score 0):

`%h` is the abbreviated SHA hash format specifier for [git log](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) --pretty.

`git log --pretty=format:%h`

Answer (score 0):

To see log output like this:

```
* ddddeee E
* zzzzzzz D
* 2222222 C
* 1111111 B
* 0000000 A
```

You can simply use

```
git log --oneline --graph
```